# Django: How to debug this admin bug? Form not rendered

Tags: python, django, forms, rendering, admin

I am facing a very strange problem. I have a Django project which runs fine in four environments (development, testing, staging and production), besides one strange bug.

In the production environment, the **change form for a single model isn't rendered anymore**. The rendered html page only contains the csrf token and then the submit buttons. All other change forms for other models are rendered just fine.

The result looks like this:
[image]

I am running the same code based (same commit and branch) on an identical staging server, and everything looks fine.

What could cause the faulty rendering of the form? How can I further debug it?

This is what I tried so far:

1. I `switched back to a commit` where I was absolutely sure that the admin change form worked. *Form still not rendered.*
2. I compared the `pip` packages between the `Staging` and `Production`. *Both are identical (Django 1.7.1)*
3. I checked the `log files` on the dev server. *No Django error found.*

I am running out of ideas how to debug this issue. Any suggestions?

**Update March 23rd**

It turns out that setting `DEBUG=True`, let's Django rendering the form. If `DEBUG=True`, the form rendering is failing silently. Why is that?

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same. Unfortunately changing the value of DEBUG in my case doesn't change things

Answer (score 0):

idea 1:DEBUG=False- static files are not handled by django but nginx /apache does

idea 2:Compare settings.py and url.py (mostly there r changes between staging/prod env's)

idea 3:For debugging run django stand-alone (runserver) without apache/fcgi